# When is it sufficient to use logic as proof for an intuitive answer

Tags: calculus, intuition

Say I have the following limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3^x}{e^{x-1}}$$

In this case it's simple enough to write it as **$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{3^x}{e^{1-x}}$** and then show it approaches infinity, but if there wasn't an easy algebraic solution would it be sufficient to state something along the lines of:

> **$3^x$** approaches infinity more quickly **$e^{x-1}$** because **$3$** is larger
>   than **$e$** and so will be grow faster with the exponential, and because
>   at each term **$e$** is being raised to a smaller exponent.

If not, would it ever be sufficient, and if so, in what context? Am I informally quoting proofs/laws in that statement without even knowing it, or is more work required?

It feels as if I'm saying things that I know to be true without actually substantiating them; it's a line I've been unable to clearly draw for myself ever since I began studying college math.

Comment: Ideally, you should always be able to support your intuition with facts, as is demonstrated in the answers below

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're simply trying to convince someone of that fact, then what you say might be sufficient.  If you're in a class, trying to demonstrate your mastery of analysis, it probably won't be enough.  In more complex problems, where logical flaws are more subtle, it also won't be enough.  There's probably some kind of intuitive core to the FLT proof assembled by Wiles, but that wouldn't supply the level of rigor necessary to verify that what he did was correct.

Comment: That was my thought. I guess it's occasionally unclear as to when I have sufficiently proven my answer. Saying the statment **1 < 2** is true because 1 is a smaller number than 2 is obviously sufficient, but with more complex math it becomes harder for me to determine when I can stop and put a box around my answer.

Comment: I think that depends exactly on the intended audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every proof start by intuition if you don't see the result intuitively it will very difficult because you will never know where to go, in your example it's clear that $\frac{3^x}{e^{x-1}}$ will tend to $\infty$ because the powers of $3$ grows faster than the powers of $e$ **because** $3>e$ now that you observed this "key" idea and the reasons why $3>e$ this idea works you can write things formally:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x}{e^{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^x\xrightarrow{\color{#a00}{3>e}}\frac{1}{e} \infty=\infty$$
and we have to make sure that we used the reason $3>e$. For me everything starts from intuition and then you try to write what you're thinking more formally and rigorously, this for the question for which the justification is not very "deep" particularly for a question like "prove that:$\cdots$" . Sometimes you can not  start from intuition when for examples you try to solve an equation and this case you're not trying to "justify" something but you're looking for the solutions or for the formula let's say for the answer so in the beginning your work is to find the answer and you don't really do things formally and in the end when you found the answer you have to write things formally and rigorously.

Comment: So to clarify, what about **$\frac{1}{e}({\frac{3}{e}})^x = \infty$** is more formal or rigorous that just saying that  **$\frac{3^x}{e^{x-1}} = \infty$**? It's not introducing anything knew, just stating it more verbosely. I get the gist of what your saying, just trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: Note that  "writing things formally" means for me using the theorems of the course or the definitions or $\cdots$ because writing $\lim_{x\to \infty} a^x=\infty$ when $0\leq a<1$ is more formal than the other one because it's well used theorem or proposition which is in general proved by the definition using $\epsilon$

Comment: Although this post is old, I cannot resist to disagree. With intuition, you can get far, but for example, can you see, intuitively, why a group of order $p²$ with p prime must be abelian? I can't  tbh.

Answer (score 2):

hint: $\dfrac{3^x}{e^{x-1}} > \dfrac{3^{x-1}}{e^{x-1}} = \left(\dfrac{3}{e}\right)^{x-1}$

Answer (score 1):

You should rather rewrite $$\frac{3^x}{e^{x-1}}=\frac{e^{x\ln 3}}{e^{x-1}}=e^{x\ln 3-x+1}=e^{x(\ln 3-1)+1}$$
and then argue that $\ln 3-1>0$ (whihc is the case precisely because $3>e$).

Comment: @JordanGlen Ack